# Holding Command-S to enter Single User Mode fails on keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard

Cannot boot into Applejack with wired aluminum Apple keyboard. Another wired keyboard (old but goodie) works. Fault may be a signal failure via the USB cable. Any comments on repair?

Comment: Are you looking for how to repair? Where to repair? Whether to repair?

Comment: Here's a comment: Repairing the keyboard is probably a good idea.

Comment: Having the same problem quite often (many Macs at work), some Macs do not seem to accept startup modifiers from the aluminium keyboards, though I haven´t exactly pin-pointed the problem. Is there a Firmware update available for either you Mac or your Keyboard?

Comment: Problem not solved but is not critical. Thanks for your comment, Asmus.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, there is no issue with either keyboard.  iMacs with Intel Core Duos and G4/G5 machines need that old school keyboard for it to be recognized before the OS is loaded. I've tested this on several Macs including Snow Leopard OS's.